# Text starting at wrong position in textview in Xcode 6

Tags: ios8, uitextview

There's no code involved at the moment, only storyboard or xib files as far as the textview is concerned. This is what I get when running the app on my iPhone 5s or via the simulator.
I'm using auto layout and size classes with the option any width-any height. An imageview at the top, then a label, then the textview.
Here's a picture of the screen. As you can see, it looks as if the text is starting behind the label, but the textview's y is after the label and the constraints seem all correct according to Xcode 6. It works fine on iPad.
Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?
[image: screenshot of the textview]

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way round it: textview should have no scrolling enabled and should be put in a scrollview instead, which will do the actual scrolling. Need to add constraints to both.